# Blender API return the same camera position for every rendered frame

Tags: python, rendering, camera

I have a path and camera following that path. I need to print the camera position for every rendered frame.

```
cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
s = bpy.context.scene 

for fr in range(s.frame_start, 15):
    print(fr)
    fileName = '/shot_%d.jpg' % fr
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = PATH_TO_SAVE + fileName
    s.frame_set(fr)
    #s.frame_current = fr
    s.update()   
    print(cam.location)
    print(cam.rotation_euler)
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Frames rendered pictures are the correct - camera is moving along the path, but cam.location and cam.rotation_euler remains the same during all frames.

```
<Vector (7.4811, -6.5076, 5.3437)>
<Euler (x=1.4456, y=-0.4655, z=1.9483), order='XYZ'>
<Vector (7.4811, -6.5076, 5.3437)>
<Euler (x=1.4456, y=-0.4655, z=1.9483), order='XYZ'>
<Vector (7.4811, -6.5076, 5.3437)>
<Euler (x=1.4456, y=-0.4655, z=1.9483), order='XYZ'>
```

How to fix this and get camera position for every rendered frame?

Comment: `cam = scene.camera`  and use `cam.matrix_world.to_translation()` and  `cam.matrx_world.to_euler()` to get the visual world  location and rotation.

Comment: ... and `s.render_filepath = ...` since the context scene may not always be named "Scene"